# How to display basic Account Information for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering if a user logs in using the login controller for asp.net, how do I display the users information in a "My Account" page.  Do I simply do that through C# and SQL?  Is there something that gets stored when a user logins already so I can return the username anywhere in the project?

Comment: C# is already in the tags. No need to put it in the title, especially since your question doesn't depend on C#

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ASP.NET Membership:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried LoginStatus and LoginName ASP.NET controls?